# How to rename multiple video files

Tags: powershell, video, renaming

I have multiple videos, and they all have different titles to them. For example one is called The_Speaker's_Wrath_1982_, another is called Forest_Spirit_1977_ and they all have different titles but look like that..with the underscore's. I was wondering if it's possible to rename all the videos I have, to like The Speaker's Wrath (1982), Forest Spirit (1977) to rename them like that. It prolly looks stupid, but if it can be done that would be cool. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: this should be a trivial request for someone with knowledge of powershell (which you have available by default in windows 7).  tag your question with powershell and see if you get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing are all .avi files and all in one folder you can do that in a powershell console from that folder:

```
get-childItem *.avi | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_',' '  -replace '\d{4}', '($0)' }
```

side note: if the title contains a number of 4 digit it will be enclosed in `()` too.

Comment: The video files are multiple formats sometimes, like .avi, .mp4, .wmv, .mkv and so on. But how would powershell know to rename the item properly?

Comment: If you isolate all of the videos into the same folder (I think you may already have done that) you should be able to change the `*.avi` to `*.*` (towards the beginning of the powershell command) so that it will look at all files in the folder (rather than just .avi files).

Comment: you may need to adjust the `'\d{4}'` towards the end of the command with `' \d{4} '` so that the spaces around the 4 digit number are included in the text that gets replaced with the number in parenthesis.  I would recommend copying a few files into a separate folder to experiment on before running the command on the entire folder (you ought to have a backup of the files - just in case anything goes wrong).

Comment: @C.B.,dav1dsmi1th: Moving files would prove a problem for me as they often have associated nfo,tbn,jpg. You can avoid this by using the following instead: `code Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\videos" -Include @("*.avi","*.mp4","*.mkv","*.wmv") `

Comment: So how would the full command look, C.B.,dav1dsmi1th..with your line added in? I'm confused..sorry

Comment: `get-childItem -Path "C:\videos" -Include @("*.avi","*.mp4","*.mkv","*.wmv") | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_',' '  -replace '\s\d{4}\s', '($0)' }`    you substitute the path to your folder for c:\videos and add any other video formats in the set between the brackets